# How to properly use hitTest between bitmapData and an object?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, bitmapdata

I have converted a PNG into a bitmap, then converted that into bitmapData.

I have a object called `_player`, and I wish to add collision detection, however I can seem to get it to work.

my code is:

```
if(bmd1.hitTest(new Point(_player.x, _player.y))){
trace("hit");
}
```

bmd1 is my `bitmapData`,`_player` is the object is wish to test against.

I am getting the following error:

```
1136: Incorrect number of arguments, Expected 3
```

I have looked around but cannott find what argument I am missing

Any ideas?

**Update**

I have tried

```
if(bmd1.hitTest(new Point(_player.x, _player.y), 50, _player)){
trace("hit");
}
```

with no joy

**Update 2**

Sorry, I should mention that the reason for me taking this approach is that I have a PNG, with transparent areas, I need to test for collisions in the *non-transparent* areas, which is why I was using this approach

I have a PNG, i import that and convert to bitmap, then convert to `bitmapData`

I maybe doing this completely wrong. Could you show me where the problem lies?

Comment: hitTest on a BitmapData object is a bit different to the methods found in normal display objects. Are you sure you didn't want to run the hitTest against your Bitmap instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end I converted my player movieclip to bitmapdata, converted my png map to bitmap data, then used hitTest to check the x and y of each bitmap against each other

Answer (score 6):

hitTest has 3 mandatory arguments:

```
public function hitTest(firstPoint:Point, firstAlphaThreshold:uint, secondObject:Object, secondBitmapDataPoint:Point = null, secondAlphaThreshold:uint = 1)
```

Check the [doc](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/BitmapData.html#hitTest%28%29)

Answer (score 0):

The method you want is hitTestPoint() not hitTest()

EDIT: whoops I missed that you were doing the hit test against BitmapData instead of a DisplayObject. BitmapData.hitTest() performs pixel-level detection which is pretty slow in many situations. You're probably better off putting the BitmapData into a Sprite and then using hitTestPoint()

Comment: BitmapData does not have a hitTestPoint method, it's a bit different to other DisplayObjects.

Comment: Place the BitmapData inside a Sprite and it's problem solved.

Comment: oh, he's running the hit test directly on the bitmap data? That's weird; I would run the hit test on a Sprite which has that BitmapData. I generally treat BitmapData as just the static image information and Sprite as an interactive object.